# Monster in pond, possibly enters house from beneath a sink?

Tags: story-identification, horror, dinosaurs

A creature lives in a pond and sucks a kid in or something and somehow enters the house beneath the sink or somewhere.

It's a 4 legged monster, dinosaurian.

Comment: When did you read it? How long was it? Was it aimed at younger readers or adults? Any more details you can remember to narrow this down would help us immensely

Comment: Also, movie, novel, comic? What language was it in?

Comment: Movie form and I watched it around 1990